# Multilevel models: Meaning of random intercept

Tags: repeated-measures, sas, mixed-model

I am quite confused at the moment regarding multilevel models as implemented in SAS PROC MIXED. I am new to mixed models.

Let's say I have 2 treatments, a new treatment and a control. And let's say that I have a sample of n subjects, each is contributing 1, 2 or 3 samples, i.e., the treatment (new or control) is being applied in 1 to 3 places in the subject's body.

I can't understand the difference between:

```
Proc mixed data=...
class Treatment SubjectID;
model Y = Treatment;
Random SubjectID;
run;
```

and

```
Proc mixed data=...
class Treatment SubjectID;
model Y = Treatment;
Random intercept / subject = SubjectID;
run;
```

I can't figure out this intercept / slope issue and its meaning.

Comment: I think this question should be left here; while it is about SAS code, answering the question requires knowledge of statistics. The SAS part is easy (delete or add a word), the statistics part is not.

Comment: @PeterFlom Happy to accept that, but will someone please edit the post title (and possibly contents) to make that more evident?

Comment: @NickCox I just did so

Answer (score 3):

Continuing @Peter Flom's example, it is equivalent to write the following two blocks:

```
proc mixed data=rc;
   class Batch;
   model Y = ;
   random batch;
run;

proc mixed data=rc;
   class Batch;
   model Y = ;
   random int / subject=batch;
run;
```

This first block adds a random effect term for each level of `batch`.
The second block adds a random intercept and specifies that it varies from `'subject'` to `'subject'`.

Answer (score 2):

In an ordinary regression we model

$Y = XB + \epsilon$

and `SAS` (as other programs) automatically adds an intercept.

In a multilevel model we model

$Y = XB + Z\gamma + \epsilon $

By default, `SAS` does not add an intercept to the Z matrix. Adding intercept does that.

To see this, try running the model with and without intercept. E.g., on Example 5 in the MIXED documentation:

```
data rc;
   input Batch Month @@;
   Monthc = Month;
   do i = 1 to 6;
      input Y @@;
      output;
   end;
   datalines;
 1   0  101.2 103.3 103.3 102.1 104.4 102.4
 1   1   98.8  99.4  99.7  99.5    .     .
 1   3   98.4  99.0  97.3  99.8    .     .
 1   6  101.5 100.2 101.7 102.7    .     .
 1   9   96.3  97.2  97.2  96.3    .     .
 1  12   97.3  97.9  96.8  97.7  97.7  96.7
 2   0  102.6 102.7 102.4 102.1 102.9 102.6
 2   1   99.1  99.0  99.9 100.6    .     .
 2   3  105.7 103.3 103.4 104.0    .     .
 2   6  101.3 101.5 100.9 101.4    .     .
 2   9   94.1  96.5  97.2 95.6     .     .
 2  12   93.1  92.8  95.4 92.2   92.2  93.0
 3   0  105.1 103.9 106.1 104.1 103.7 104.6
 3   1  102.2 102.0 100.8  99.8    .     .
 3   3  101.2 101.8 100.8 102.6    .     .
 3   6  101.1 102.0 100.1 100.2    .     .
 3   9  100.9  99.5 102.2 100.8    .     .
 3  12   97.8  98.3  96.9  98.4  96.9  96.5
 ;


proc mixed data=rc;
   class Batch;
   model Y = Month / s;
   random Int Month / type=un sub=Batch s;
run;
```

the output includes a solution for the random effect of an intercept.

Running

```
proc mixed data=rc;
   class Batch;
   model Y = Month / s;
   random batch / type=un sub=Batch s;
run;
```

does not. This also changes other results.